# Minimum TLS version for google cloud standard app engine projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-standard

We have multiple standard app engine projects that needs restriction on the tls version (>= 1.2), is there a setting to change that through the console?

Answer (score 2):

To change the support TLS versions requires an [SSL policy](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-policies-concepts). SSL policies can only be applied to HTTP(S) Load Balancers and SSL Proxy Load Balancers.

You can create an HTTP(S) Load Balancer and a backend configured for App Engine. That is the only method to change supported TLS versions.

[Update 2023-08-06]

See the [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1140928/437769) by @intotecho about using a constraints.

[Restrict TLS versions](https://cloud.google.com/assured-workloads/docs/restrict-tls-versions)

Comment: Thx, I've seen people saying opening a ticket to gcp would allow them to make the changes, do you have any information confirming that?

Comment: I am not aware of Google Support supporting manual changes to TLS for App Engine. I do not actually know for sure, but I doubt it based upon internal knowledge. If you have a reference, I will look into this.

Comment: @JohnHanley The ability to configure TLS minimum versions is alluded to in a google app engine group discussion at https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine/c/W-RSgayAb_I/m/620NKq5kCQAJ
I'm assuming that is out of date.

Answer (score 2):

There's now a way to restrict TLS Versions by Organization Policy without configuring a Load Balancer:
[Policy for Restrict TLS Versions](https://cloud.google.com/assured-workloads/docs/restrict-tls-versions)

You need `roles/orgpolicy.policyAdmin` to configure it.

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/orgpolicies?

The policy covers appengine.googleapis.com and many Google APIs.

In the next few quarters,

> "The App Engine frontend will be "secure by default" (tentatively,
> this means TLS1.2+ and aligning with the Cloud Load-balancing Modern
> profile) [ref](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Security/How-to-Disable-TLS-1-0-and-1-1-in-AppEngine-site-How-to-active/m-p/607512/highlight/true#M1117)

As @beano commented, and my testing confirms, this doesn't work for App Engine (yet). But it does work for Cloud Storage.

"Using an Organization Policy as a way of restricting TLS versions does not apply to App Engine, Cloud Functions, Cloud Run and custom domains. See restricted services."

**EDIT - App Engine is possibly blocking TLS1.1 now!**

Testing today (Sept 15 2023), App Engine does seem to be blocking TLS1.1

```
function test_tls_protocol_version() {
  if [ $# -lt 3 ]
  then
    echo "Error in arguments"
    echo "usage:  $0 TLS version bearer url"
    echo "version=$1"
    echo "bearer=$2"
    echo "url=$3"
    exit
  fi
  version="$1"
  bearer="$2"
  url="$3"

  echo Testing TLS Version $'\033[33;5m'$version$'\033[0m' on site: $'\033[33;5m'$url$'\033[0m'
  curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $bearer" $url --tlsv$version --tls-max $version
}
```

testing with:

```
test_tls_protocol_version 1.1 $ndpe_uat_bearer "https://<project>.ey.r.appspot.com"
```

results in

```
curl: (35) error:141E70BF:SSL routines:tls_construct_client_hello:no protocols available
```

while 1.2 is returning a result.

However, the results of openssl are inconclusive. This is the test used by Qualys.

```
openssl s_client -connect <project_id>.ey.r.appspot.com:443 -tls1
openssl s_client -connect <project_id>.ey.r.appspot.com:443 -tls1_1
openssl s_client -connect <project_id>.ey.r.appspot.com:443 -tls1_2
```

All give similar results, compared with say microsoft.com

```
openssl s_client -connect microsoft.com:443 -tls1_1
openssl s_client -connect microsoft.com:443 -tls1_2
```

Comment: Thank you for adding an answer about the `restrictTLSVersion` constraint.

Comment: Using an Organization Policy as a way of restricting TLS versions does not apply to App Engine, Cloud Functions, Cloud Run and custom domains. See [restricted services](https://cloud.google.com/assured-workloads/docs/restrict-tls-versions#unsupported-services).

We also put in a support request to GCP to see whether they can set the minimum without a Load Balancer but they refused to do it (although they have done it for others) and said a Load Balancer was the only option. Hopefully they set the minimum by default in these services soon, otherwise we have no choice to move to AWS.

Comment: It's not blocking yet. You can verify using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html or

````nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 <yourdomain.com>````